# Jquery is not targeting the last instance of an object on a page

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Thanks to some help on here I've got a neat little piece of jquery in my loop that does the following.

On my excerpt page, when a post has the custom field 'takeaway' filled in, a second button is added to the post alongside the standard 'read more' which takes them to an anchor within the permalink.

The jquery is added in to target the 'read more' button which has a class of .more and add the class .small which shrinks it down to 50% so the new button sits alongside nicely.

The issue is, for some strange reason, it will not target the last instance of .more on the page regardless of how many posts are on the page the class .small is just not added to the last one on the page.

Can anyone help?

```
<?php $key = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'takeaway', true);    
if($key) : ?> 
<script>
$(".takeaway").parent().find(".more").addClass("small");
</script>
<a class="takeaway" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#thetakeaway" rel="bookmark">Quick+Dirty!</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: So you're saying the class is added to all instances of $key except when $key is true on the last instance, in which case the class isn't added regardless? Do you have a link by chance?

Comment: Try to replicate your issue on jsfiddle and provide in your question more context of your code.

Comment: That is exactly right. I don't have a link I'm afraid as it's a WP site in maintenance mode with Admin access only. More than happy to add any more details here that you may need...

Comment: I can't replicate on jsfiddle as it's in the middle of the loop on a Wordpress install and won't be a good testing environment? Just thought I'd ask incase there is something obvious I'm missing...

Comment: What gives you: `$(".takeaway").parent().find(".more").addClass("small"); alert($('.small').length);` Expected number of `.small` elements?

Comment: It's because you're trying to run JavaScript on an element that's not on the page yet. You want to put your script call inside a `domready` event handler.

Comment: That gives me two alerts, the first says "0" the second says "1". I have two instances of .more on the page currently. Forgive my ignorance, is this good or bad?

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks for the help. Are you able to give me an example of this please. I'm still very new to jquery...

Comment: @user2272355 so you are targeting elements before adding all in the DOM. You should really provide more context on how you are using your code. I don't know WP so...

Comment: @A.Wolff The code is used inside of a php loop which checks for posts in Wordpress and displays them on the page. It's in a normal content.php page in the Twenty Twelve theme.

Comment: @user2272355 why don't you post the PHP loop code you are using? Really sorry about my ignorance regarding WP

Comment: That's ok @A.Wolff the loop contains several php files pulled together so it's not something I can post. I really appreciate your help but if you're not familiar with WP you may not be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're trying to run JavaScript on an element `$(".takeaway")` that's not on the page yet. First you want to just output the link element with your `takeaway` class based on your key:

```
<?php $key = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'takeaway', true);    
if ($key) : ?> 
<a class="takeaway" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#thetakeaway" rel="bookmark">Quick+Dirty!</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And then right before the `</body>` tag, in your `domready` event handler, add the script to add the `small` class to the intended elements: The `$key = ...` part is required again otherwise the `$key` var would be undefined and an error would occur.

```
<?php $key = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'takeaway', true);
if ($key) : ?> 
<script type="javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".takeaway").parent().find(".more").addClass("small");
});
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately it breaks the page at the first instance and nothing loads thereafter...

Comment: There is no error on the screen. The first post that has .more loads, then nothing else below that loads at all...

Comment: @user2272355 by the screen, you mean the console, right?!

Comment: Didn't realize you were using wordpress here. The problem is because the `$key` variable is undefined in the context of the script that holds the `</body>` tag. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Forgive me, I had misread you're code exmaple. I've done as you suggested, don't get any errors and the page loads fine but none of the .more objects have .small attached. Can I ask what you mean by put it in your domready event handler?

Comment: I've used your edited answer but its same as my last comment. Everything loads ok, the javascript does not target anything on the page though...

Comment: Fixed it! Using your code. The issue was that putting it before the </body> means it's out of the WP Loop. I've added it directly after the first piece of code and now it works. Thanks for your help!